# Adding jsf attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2

I'm working with jsf 2.0 and jquery 1.9.

I'm trying to create a placeholder for an input field. However, jsf 2.0 removed the placeholder attribute for `<h:inputText>` components. I believe the jquery 1.9 has something to add attributes to certain components, but honestly, I've never used jquery.

What's the syntax to add the placeholder attribute?

Thanks!

--EDIT--
I'm adding a bit more of code to give a bit of context.

```
<h:inputText id="input" value="#{bean.getValue}" />
```

I need this to be rendered with a placeholder that says "Fill me".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$('#input').attr('placeholder', 'Fill me');`

Of course, be aware that the placeholder attribute is not fully supported in some browsers.